# Invoke MethodInvoker Delegate for more than 1 item at a time

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, invoke

The code below works just fine but I am looking for a way to combine all 3 into just one invoke statement:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () {
   String.Format(
       "------------------------------------------------------------")
   );
}));

this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () {
   String.Format(
       "- END " + archiveFullName + " -"
   );
}));

this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () {
   String.Format(
       "------------------------------------------------------------")
   );
}));
```

I've already tried:

```
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () {
   listBox1.Items.Add(
      this.listBox1.Items.Add("--------------------------------------------------------")
      this.listBox1.Items.Add("- END " + archiveFullName + " -")
      this.listBox1.Items.Add("-------------------------------------------------------")
   );
}));
```

But that does not seem to work.

Any resolution would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(...
```